# Cosa vuol dire "ha risolto" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> BECCHINO (*senza prender fiato*)
>        
>   Grazie. Piuttosto, mi sapreste dire se abita qui un certo Prampolini Sergio? Non
>   so se al primo o al secondo piano, o anche al quarto, a meno che non ci sia un sottotetto...?
>   
>   LUIGI     
>   Sì, sta sopra, al terzo piano. Ma so di sicuro che non
>   è in casa. È all’ospedale! È sempre ammalato, poveraccio... una brutta vita!
>   
>   BECCHINO (*senza prender fiato*)
>       
>   Infatti è morto.
>   
>   GIOVANNI     
>   **Ha risolto**!

Non capisco cosa vuol dire Giovanni quando afferma che questo Prampolini Sergio "ha risolto". Significa forse che è morto? Potreste spiegarmelo? Ho cercato alla voce "risolvere" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* e ho visto che al [numero 4](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI16/00837.jpg) appare questa accezione:

> Fare cessare la vita.

Tuttavia, mi è sembrato strano che tutti e due gli esempi di uso di questo verbo con tale significato siano rinascimentali (si veda [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00060.jpg) e [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00265.jpg)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per comprendere lo scambio, teniamo conto che si tratta di una commedia. Il commento di Giovanni è una battuta. Con «ha risolto», si intende che finalmente Sergio Prampolini ha risolto i suoi problemi di malato… morendo. La battuta può sembrare macabra, ma l’umorismo ha, tra i suoi meccanismi per strappare una risata, anche slittamenti di questo tipo.