# "Vedete qui" oppure "vedi qui"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11394) avevo scritto "vedete qui" (adesso ho corretto), ma poi ho avuto il dubbio  se questa fosse un'espressione solita in italiano moderno. Ho pensato che magari avrei dovuto usare "vedi qui" e che questo "vedete qui" mi era forse venuto fuori per influenza della mia lingua (in catalano usiamo "vegeu", seconda persona plurale dell'imperativo). Infatti, ho ricercato "vedete qui" su Google Libri e ho trovato soltanto esempi arcaici.

Quindi, è veramente così? Cioè, nell'italiano attuale si usa di solito "vedi qui" invece di "vedete qui"?

Comment: “Vedete qui” non mi aveva fatto saltare sulla sedia ma, a ripensarci, in un testo scritto effettivamente io metterei forse “vedi qui” o, più spesso (ma dipende dal registro), “si veda qui”, per esempio in una nota bibliografica di un saggio.

Comment: @DaG: Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: Usare «si veda», vale a dire la forma impersonale, evita problemi di comunicazione (singolare/plurale, formale/informale).

Comment: Io personalmente direi invece "vedere qui", e anzi di solito cerco di evitare 'qui' + link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Vedete qui” non suona particolarmente strano, ma direi effettivamente che siano più usuali, in un testo scritto, forme come:

- “vedi [qui]”;
- “si veda [qui]”, forse più frequente in un testo edito e di registro un po' più sostenuto; la forma impersonale evita problemi di comunicazione (singolare/plurale, formale/informale); è quello che in genere si troverebbe in una nota bibliografica di un saggio;
- “vedere [qui]”.

In ognuno degli esempi, a seconda dei casi, “[qui]” potrebbe essere un link o gli estremi di un testo citato (per esempio “si veda [Rossi 89]”). Per la costruzione con il “si”, se si fa riferimento a più di un elemento, il plurale è “si vedano” (è la cosiddetta costruzione del “si passivante”).

Per i testi editi, in certi casi è la casa editrice stessa che, per uniformità, prevede nelle sue norme editoriali quale sia la forma da seguire.

<sub>Mi sono permesso di includere nella risposta la sostanza dei commenti di Benedetta e Federico Poloni.</sub>

Comment: E con un oggetto plurale sarebbe "si vedano", vero?

Comment: È curioso perché in catalano, come ho scritto nella domanda, è sempre "vegeu" (traduzione letterale "vedete"), mentre invece in castigliano è sempre "véase" (traduzione letterale "si veda") oppure "véanse" (traduzione letterale "si vedano").

Comment: Un'altra possibilità, di registro ancora più sostenuto, è *vedasi* (enclitico).